# SimpleXML - Cannot get attributes of first tag

Tags: php, simplexml

I am trying to read the attributes of the first tag of an XML.
Here's the XML structure

```
<myxml timestamp="1301467801">
    <tag1>value1</tag1>
    <tag2>value2</tag2>
    …
</myxml>
```

And here's how I try to get the **timestamp** attribute (tried 2 approaches, listing them both here, none works)

```
$timestamp = $xml->myxml->attributes()->timestamp; //gives Node no longer exists warning
if($xml->myxml && $xml->myxml->attributes()){ //Doesn't enter this loop
    $arr = $xml->myxml->attributes();
    $timestamp = $arr['timestamp'];
}
```

Can someone please let me know how I can get the attribute's value? Thanks.

Comment: please provide a reproducable test case. From the example above it's hard to guess what you are doing wrong. My assumption would be that `$xml` actually refers to the `<myxml>` node instead of `->myxml`. But the Node no longer exists Warning might imply some other misuse as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because your `$xml` actually points to the root element. Correct usage would be:

`$timestamp = $xml->attributes()->timestamp;`

Answer (score 3):

The right way to access attributes [as long as they belong to the node's namespace] is to use the array notation. Reserve `attributes` for namespaced attributes.

Also, you should name the variable that represent your XML document after its root node. It's a good practice that prevents many mixups.

```
$myxml = simplexml_load_string(
    '<myxml timestamp="1301467801">
        <tag1>value1</tag1>
        <tag2>value2</tag2>
    </myxml>'
);

echo $myxml['timestamp'];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$myxml = simplexml_load_string(
        '<myxml timestamp="1301467801">
        <tag1>value1</tag1>
        <tag2>value2</tag2>
    </myxml>'
);

$test = $myxml['timestamp'];
// will asign simpleXMLElement
echo $test; // -> will print nothing

// you need to cast the simpleXMLElement attribute as STRING!!! 
$test = (string)$myxml['timestamp'];
echo $test;
?>
```