# How to Access @attribute from SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml

I am having a problem accessing the @attribute section of my SimpleXML object.

XML FILE:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PrintData name="Joseph" g="M"/>
```

PHP:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstring);
echo $xml->PrintData['name'];
```

Comment: FYI http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SimpleXML - Cannot get attributes of first tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5483877/simplexml-cannot-get-attributes-of-first-tag)

Comment: You could use `echo $xml->attributes()->name;`